# Mock a static method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, jmock

I want to write a test case that will verify a method in my class. 
I have a local `ApplicationLauncher` object in my method that has to be mocked because it calls a method, `launch()`, which should not be called in a unit test.

```
public class RunApp
{
   public void check(String name)
   {
     if(name !=null)
     {
       ApplicationLauncher launcher = Application.getLauncher("launch");
       String appName = name+".bat";
       launcher.launch(appName);
     }
   }
 }
```

My JUnit test code is below:

```
RunApp runapp = new RunApp();

@Mock
ApplicationLauncher launcher;

@Test
public void test()
{
  runapp.check("test");
  verify(launcher,atLeastOnce).launch(anyString());
}
```

I am not able to return a mock object like

```
when(Application.getLauncher(anyString())).thenReturn(launcher);
```

since `getLauncher` is a static method in `Application` class. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better application design might be to have `ApplicationLauncher` as an interface and create production and test implementations (or just mock the test implementation). You would need to pass an instance of `ApplicationLauncher` into your `RunApp` class, perhaps in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock static methods using [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/), however you should check whether the static method call is really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could refactor your class to accept the launcher to be "injected".

```
public class RunApp
{
  public void check(String name)
  {
    check(name, Application.getLauncher("launch"));
  }

  protected check(String name, ApplicationLauncher launcher) {
    if (name != null)
    {
      String appName = name + ".bat";
      launcher.launch(appName);
    }
  }
}
```

That way you could use the new package-protected check() method to test your code using a fake launcher.